# Ubuntu doesn't support Seamless Mode in VirtualBox

Tags: unity, graphics, virtualbox

[Partially related to this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/136397/seamless-mode-not-working-correctly-in-virtual-box)...

I have Ubuntu 14.04 in a VM running on my Windows host. When I enter seamless mode, nothing happens at all. Nothing Ubuntu is on my screen. How do I properly use Seamless mode with Windows?

I am running VirtualBox 4.3.12 as well as the latest Guest Additions.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to the issue with unity effect in ubuntu 14.04. Start with out seamless mode do the following things

```
 sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

In `compizconfig-settings-manager`

1. set "Active window shadow color" Opacity to 0.
2. set "Inactive window shadow color" Opacity to 0.
3. checked "Override Theme Settings"

Comment: Nope, does nothing at all.

Comment: I did this because I was having the same problem, it gives me this awkward broken half-seamless mode where the size of the window isnt fullscreen as seamless should be

Comment: @taronish4 Weird. For me there's no change